# How can I use and store emojis in an iOS chat app in my MySQL database

Tags: ios, emoji

I am creating an app in iOS where users can send messages to each other. 
These messages are saved in a `MySQL` database using a service in `PHP`.

I want to add emojis, so that users can send messages containing an emoji. I researched online but haven't been able to find any information regarding this except some unicodes for emoji icons.

How can I get an emoji from a user in `UITextField` and save it in my `MySQL` text field?
How can I then display that emoji in `UILabel`.

Answer (score 2):

Emoji is just text. NSString supports it. The user must enable the emoji keyboard if they want to type it.

Comment: Well when I add emoji in text field. It show it's icon. But when it's saved in database and displayed in UILabel, it just displays a question mark '?'.

Comment: Then something is wrong with your encoding/decoding pipeline.

Comment: Can you please show me a basic example of encoding/decoding which would work for emoji?